how to track visits to a Google Sheet that is published to the web?
I want to know how many visits to my published Google Sheet I'm getting.
I wrote a script for my Google Sheet using Apps Script that writes a timestamp to the sheet, then I created a trigger that invokes it whenever the sheet is visited.  But this only works for visits to my unpublished sheet (that only I can access and edit).  It doesn't work for the sheet that I published to the web using File => Share => Publish to Web.  How can I make it work for this published version of my sheet that is publicly available?
I don't know what else to try.  The "Add Trigger for Tracking Tool" wizard has a way to select the event source, but it only includes the options: 1) From spreadsheet, 2) Time-driven, 3) From calendar.

Since it was a published one I am afraid that there is nothing else you can do about it. There is also a strong chance that you are looking at this problem differently and you might need to reevaluate how you are sharing the Sheets instead, instead of directly sharing how you are doing it how about using this as an iframe and from the HTML sides of things you can do what you need to work on.

The trigger will only fire when the user at the keyboard has edit rights to the spreadsheet. If you are not planning to share the spreadsheet so that anyone in the world can edit it, you should use some other method. The easiest way would probably be to embed the spreadsheet in a web page, and track visits to that page instead of tracking visits to the spreadsheet.

Google Apps Script doesn't have a method for the publish-to-web version of a spreadsheet or any other Google Editors files.
The only option is to embed the publish-to-web version into a website that allows you to track visits. If you want to keep everything in the Google "realm," try Google Sites. Concerning track visits, you might use Google Analytics. See Use Analytics with your Site for details.

Got it, thanks.  What about tracking requests for one of the images on the sheet?  These are referenced by URL, shared publicly from my private Google Drive.  For example:
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1B65qDGUQKYx8y2dWQGSajLEF7lZcSCBx")

@PhilHadley, follow-up questions should be posted as new questions instead of being asked in comments. Anyway, it's precisely the same regarding tracking views of the use of =IMAGE. You should host your image using a service that allows image views.

My comment @Wicket was not a separate question but rather an alternative solution to solve the same problem:  Is it possible to track requests to images on the page as a surrogate (rather than tracking requests to the entire page)?
